# wmiprvse.exe does a lot of disk seeking activity once every day

Tags: windows-xp, wmi

`wmiprvse.exe` process does a lot of disk activity, working with all files in `system32` directory (according to filemon).
Any other process which wants to do smth with disk is very slow while wmiprvse.exe scans system32. Such scans are every day and long up to tens minutes.

What does wmiprvse.exe do in my system32 and can I limit this activity?

Comment: Do you run HPWA as outlined to be a problem in the above duplicate?

Comment: I hav on HPWA, because I have no HP laptop. Also, my problem is not a CPU usage, but a disk usage (I hear it and the hdd lamp is shining). I checked task manager - there is small cpu activity from wmiprv. FileMon shows me a lot of dll and other file accesses. Also, my system partition is defragmented.

Comment: You might want to use procmon.exe and procexp.exe from Sysinternals to diagnose the behavior.

Comment: Check out [how comment @-replies work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work), or people won't get informed by your replies.